# How to have two text boxes occupy 3:1 in SWT?

Tags: java, swt

I am trying to have two textboxes, one textbox to occupy 3/4th of the screen space and the other textbox to occupy 1/4th of the screen space in SWT.

I am using grid layout as follows:

```
    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
    gridLayout.numColumns = 1;
    final Text text0 = new Text (shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    final Text text1 = new Text (shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    shell.setLayout(gridLayout);
    text0.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
    text1.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL,200)); //this line needs some help
```

Currently the first text box occupies the 3/4 of the space, but the second text box doesn't fill the entire horizontal space.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about horizontal space use a 4 column grid and make the first text span 3 columns:

```
// 4 equals sized columns
shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, true));

final Text text0 = new Text(shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP | SWT.V_SCROLL);

// First text spans 3 columns
text0.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 3, 1));

final Text text1 = new Text(shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP | SWT.V_SCROLL);

// Second text is single column
text1.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
```

Dividing up the space vertically is much more tricky as using the row span field of `GridData` with the 'grab excess space' field doesn't work very well. The best I can come up with uses dummy `Label` controls to get four equals rows:

```
shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

new Label(shell, SWT.LEAD).setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.FILL, false, true));

final Text text0 = new Text(shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP | SWT.V_SCROLL);

// First text spans 3 rows
text0.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 3));

new Label(shell, SWT.LEAD).setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.FILL, false, true));
new Label(shell, SWT.LEAD).setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.FILL, false, true));
new Label(shell, SWT.LEAD).setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.FILL, false, true));

final Text text1 = new Text(shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP | SWT.V_SCROLL);

// Second text is single row
text1.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));
```